# How do Iazy-load and pre-render a ViewController with a UIWebView upon app launch?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm working on an app that has a series of hierarchical UITableViewControllers, until you are eventually taken to a UIWebView that contains the information you're looking for. It works fine except that when the UIWebView loads it takes a while to render and flashes white before loading (All my views, including the UITableViewControllers and HTML files, have a black background)

Once the UIWebView has been both loaded and displayed it's not so much a problem- I have it load up an empty HTML page with a black background while it loads the content- but the first time it's always slow, and gives me the white flash.

I've tried to pre-render the UIWebView by initializing it and loading it while the previous UITableViewController is still active, but it doesn't seem to work. It lets me define all the necessary parameters, but calling the loadView method, nor anything else I've tried, has cajoled it into actually loading up that black background HTML before it pushes the UIWebView on screen.

Ideally what I'd like it to do is just initialize the UIWebView in the background once the app starts, such that by the time it gets pushed onto the navigation stack for the user to see, it's already preloaded with that black background so there's  no white flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`?

Comment: It still flashes white the first time, seems to be for a shorter period though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find and answer to this.  I am doing the same thing.  I have found I can create a second webview and start populating it off screen.  I use javascript to check on the progress, so that I know it has rendered.  However about 3 seconds after I have two pages rendered (one visible and one not) it thread for web pages crashes.

My next idea is to make both screen visible just most the unused screen a mile off to the right so the end user can't see it.

Comment: What I finally wound up doing was just having a big opaque black view called "maskingView" that covered up the webView until it received didFinishedLoading delegate callback from the webView, at which point it hid maskingView. That finally did the trick.